# Condtional overwrite Primevue Class p-accordion-header

Tags: css, vue.js, class, styles, primevue

I am trying to find a solution for overwriting the primevue component class `p-accordion-header` to have different styles depending on the status of the rendered component that I can get with the `variantNumber`.

This is what my code looks like:

```
  <Accordion :multiple="true">
    <AccordionTab
      v-for="variantNumber in variants?.keys()"
      :key="'V' + variantNumber"
    >
    </AccordionTab>
  </Accordion>
```

where `variants` is a simple list.

Imagine I have a function that returns the current class name called `getCurrentVariantClass(variantNumber)`.

1. I can't add a class to the `AccordionTab` because it would be a non-props attribute.
2. I tried to wrap a `div` or a simple html tag around the `AccordionTab` and add a class there but the component won't render.

How am I supposed to overwrite the styles of `p-accordion-header` conditionally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to customize `AccordionTab` to receive a `variant` prop, we could create a new component that uses the `extends` option, and add the prop there:

```html
<!-- MyAccordionTab.vue -->
<script>
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
import AccordionTab from 'primevue/accordiontab'

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'AccordionTab', // must be named "AccordionTab" for Accordion to detect it
  extends: AccordionTab,
  props: {
    variant: Number, 
  },
  render: AccordionTab.render,
})
</script>
```

Using the same technique above, extend the `Accordion` component to override its [`getTabHeadherClass()` method](https://github.com/primefaces/primevue/blob/836609d/src/components/accordion/Accordion.vue#L111-L113) that conditionally adds a class based on the given `tab`'s `variant` prop:

```html
<!-- MyAccordion.vue -->
<script>
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
import Accordion from 'primevue/accordion'

export default defineComponent({
  extends: Accordion,
  methods: {
    getTabHeaderClass(tab, i) {
      const headerClasses = Accordion.methods.getTabHeaderClass.call(this, tab, i)
      const variantClass = this.getCurrentVariantClass(tab.props.variant)
      return headerClasses.concat(variantClass)
    },
    getCurrentVariantClass(variantNumber) {
      switch (variantNumber) {
        case 1:
          return 'p-accordion-header-variant-a'
        case 2:
          return 'p-accordion-header-variant-b'
        case 3:
          return 'p-accordion-header-variant-c'
      }
    },
  },
  render: Accordion.render,
})
</script>

<style scoped>
.p-accordion-header-variant-a .p-accordion-header-link {
  border: solid 1px red;
}
.p-accordion-header-variant-b .p-accordion-header-link {
  border: solid 1px green;
}
.p-accordion-header-variant-c .p-accordion-header-link {
  border: solid 1px blue;
}
</style>
```

Finally, use those new components in your app:

```html
<!-- App.vue -->
<script setup>
import Accordion from '@/components/MyAccordion.vue'
import AccordionTab from '@/components/MyAccordionTab.vue'

const tabs = [/*...*/]
</script>

<template>
  <Accordion multiple>
    <AccordionTab v-for="tab in tabs" :key="tab.title" :variant="tab.variant" :header="tab.title">
      <p>{{ tab.content }}</p>
    </AccordionTab>
  </Accordion>
</template>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-primevue-custom-accordion-header-class?file=src%2FApp.vue,src%2Fcomponents%2FMyAccordion.vue)